# Trying to build a counter, very basic javascript question

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to writing code and I am using JavaScript and HTML in Visual Studio Code.
I've been trying to solve the following exercise which is to create a button that counts how many times it is being pushed.

The HTML part is done, but I'm stuck in the JavaScript part.

Any advice to solve such a thing?

```js
let counter

document.querySelector("#btnPush").addEventListener("click", plus)

function plus() {

    counter = 0;
    
    document.querySelector("#pCounter").innerHTML = counter + 1
    
}
```

Comment: First: Java and JavaScript are as similar as Ham and Hamster. The code you posted is JavaScript. Second: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What element of HTML you're changing? is it an input type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let counter = 0

document.querySelector("#btnPush").addEventListener("click", plus)

function plus() {

  counter++;

  document.querySelector("#pCounter").innerHTML = counter

}
```

```html
<button id="btnPush">button</button>
<p id="pCounter">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with your code is that you define your counter inside your method. This means, that each time your method is startet, it sets the counter to zero. The soulution would be to write let counter = 0; outside of you method and then deleting the counter = 0; line inside the method

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're changing the content/value of `input type` element, which you should do by changing `value`, not `innerHTML`.

Check this out:

```html
<html>
    <p align="center">
        <input type="text" id="pCounter" style = "padding:.5%; margin:10px"></input>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="btnPush" value="Click here"></input>
    </p>

    <script>
        let counter = 0;

        document.querySelector("#btnPush").addEventListener("click", plus)

        function plus() {
            document.querySelector('#pCounter').value = ++counter;  
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic code for counter:
you can utilized it ad per your demand...

```js
        let counter = 0;

        document.querySelector("#btnadd").addEventListener("click", plus)

        function plus() {
            document.querySelector('#display').value = ++counter;  
        }
```

```html
    <p align="center">
        <input type="text" id="display">
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="btnadd" value="Click here">
    </p>
```